# Cambiar fecha de certificado de paquete UWP

Tags: visual-studio

Una pregunta si es posible o no. Tengo esta app de UWP que al momento de generar el paquete en VS no funciona correctamente. Mi pregunta es, el paquete de la imagen sí funciona bien el problema es que el certificado ya cadudó y no puedo distribuirla con el certificado nuevo ya que no es de la firma de la app. Y por tiempo no puedo arreglar el código de la app.
¿Se puede cambiar la fecha de caducidad de este certificado en el mismo paquete para reutilizarlo?
[image: Paquete funcionable]

Comment: Ni idea pero me atrevo a decir que no porque posiblemente lo que se haya firmado con ese certificado no va a ser válido. Alguien que sepa de entorno .NET seguro vendrá a aclarar mejor